# Ungrouping Will not Allow To Scroll

Tags: vba, excel, grouping, excel-2013

I am copying from one worksheet to another, and am grouping the selection.  When I click the plus sign to show the full group, I can not scroll through the grouped selection.  This is the syntax I am using to expand the group, what is it that stops me from being able to scroll through?

**Ungrouping allows me to scroll, but the data on the worksheet itself never moves, just the scroll bar on the right side of the page**

```
Set rLastCell = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Cells(1, 1), _
LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)
Range("A2:A" & rLastCell.Row).Rows.Group
ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two features in Excel that could cause this problem that I know of.  Both are under the "View" ribbon options.  Please verify that the Freeze or Split options are not active.

Comment: I am also freezing panes using this syntax - is that the culprit? Rows("2:2").Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
Range("A1").Select

Comment: My suspicion would be that your freezing syntax could be the culprit.  Freezing shows itself in many ways :)

Comment: The freezing is exaactly what was causing the issue.  Is there a way I can keep headers in taact other than freezing?